# Astonia Linux game server is unreasonably slow

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, port-forwarding, linux-server

I just set up an old MMO from 2002 or so ([Astonia](http://brockhaus.org/astonia3.html)) on a 32-bit clean install of Ubuntu, as it was just brought to my attention that the game in open source and I figured, why not? When the server is running, it takes <1% CPU and <0.5% RAM. However, when I connect with the game client from another computer in my network or outside my network, the game is slow to the point of being unplayable. I forwarded a few ports on my router (ASUS RT-N66R) to get things running, but that's as far as I've gone on the networking side.

I have about 0 experience dealing with network stuff, and not much dealing with servers in general. So, I don't know where to begin. Does this sound like a networking problem? How can I diagnose this further? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

- My download/update speed is 17.42mbps/1.18mbps, and I used to play this game on a 56k.
- Link to [server source code](http://brockhaus.org/astonia3_server.tgz).
- Link to [client source code](http://brockhaus.org/astonia3_client.zip).

Server [start log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B14bgFu9ALoXSDEzVU0tanNnX2s/view?usp=sharing):

```
   ********************************************
   *     Astonia 3 - The Conflict Server      *
   *             Version 3.01.00              *
   ********************************************
   * Copyright (C) 2001-2008 Intent Software  *
   * Copyright (C) 1997-2001 Daniel Brockhaus *
   ********************************************

No areaID given, assuming areaID=1
No mirror given, assuming areaM=1
No serverID given, assuming serverID=1
serverID=1, areaID=1, areaM=1, maxchars=512, maxitem=20480, maxeffect=1024

13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Login to database as root OK
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Using existing database merc
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: sweep_database: removed 0 characters
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Created background thread for database accesses
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated sector 0: 0.25M (4*65536)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated sector 1: 0.06M (4*16384)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated sector 2: 0.02M (4*4096)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated sector 3: 0.00M (4*1024)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated sector 4: 0.00M (4*256)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated sector 5: 0.00M (4*64)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated sector 6: 0.00M (4*16)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated sector 7: 0.00M (4*4)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated char sector: 0.00M (4*1024)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated sound sector: 0.25M (4*65536)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated shout sector: 0.25M (4*65536)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated los: 1.28M (2624*512)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated map: 1.75M (28*65536)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated items: 4.45M (228*20480)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated characters: 0.11M (1092*512)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated item templates: 0.44M (308*1500)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated character templates: 0.31M (1276*256)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/caligar.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/mr_doors.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/depot.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/sidestory.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/ice_palace_key.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/warr_keys.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/mission_bonus.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/potions.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/armor.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/ring.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/stack.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/spells.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/adornments.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/orb.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/randchest.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/lab.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/scroll.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/moonies.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/weapons.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/torch.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/swamp.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/runes.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/bonus_items.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/mr_lights.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/metal.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/mr_chairs.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/sun_amulet.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/cloth.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/culture.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/recall.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/clan.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/mr_chestbox.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/tmp.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/teufelheim.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/grave.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/alchemy.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/transport.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_village.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/sign.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_mage_castle.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_city.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_mad.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_robber.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/shrike.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_knight_castle.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_warlock.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_skeleton_maze.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_guild.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_wood.itm".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/player.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/test.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/macro.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/generic/sidestory.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_mad.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_robber.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_city.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_mage_castle.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_exp_dungron.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_knight_castle.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_exp2_dungeon.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_wood.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_village.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/shrike.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_guild.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_skeleton_maze.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1_warlock.chr".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Processing zone "./zones/1/above1.map".
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Created 139 character and 1249 item templates
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Created 292 characters and 1701 items
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Calculating daylight
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated libs: 0.01M (96*100)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated fast_chdrvs: 0.00M (4*200)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated fast_itdrvs: 0.00M (4*200)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated players: 0.00M (4*256)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Size of player data: 150956 bytes
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: IO Init done: ID=1 (212.202.240.67:5556)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated nmap: 0.25M (4*65536)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated nodes: 0.12M (32*4096)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated effects: 1.09M (1112*1024)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated containers: 0.46M (468*1024)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated store: 0.00M (4*64)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Calculating shout sectors
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: 10 shout sectors found
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Calculating talk sectors
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: 195 talk sectors found
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: Allocated sector2: 0.00M (8*196)
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: AreaID=1, AreaM=1, entering game loop...
13.02.16 17:51:51 [001-01]: ID=0: Server started
13.02.16 17:51:52 [001-01]: Read MotD
13.02.16 17:51:52 [001-01]: reset plronh 73
13.02.16 18:00:24 [001-01]: reset plronh 74
```

Comment: Could you list your router also model and info on speed

Comment: Router is already in there but I've added speed

Comment: What are the loads on the server when you are accessing the game?

Comment: How can I check this (other than CPU and RAM listed above)?

Comment: Run the game from a computer and check the resources one the server while someone is testing the game and see if anything spikes.

Comment: Nothing seems to bring it above 0.5% memory or 1.3% cpu

Comment: Could you please add a link to the game's website/point of download? Also, try to figure out if it generates a logfile - from the description you have given so far it doesn't sound very much like a network problem, rather like something very basic with the config/setup, but so far this is only advanced guessing...

Comment: @xpac I've added links as requested

Comment: Thanks. The documentation is... rather non-existant, but from the little I can see from the source code, the game is either logging to the console or to some logfile - but I couldn't find the exact name.

So, try to to locate that log output and if you can, copy it here so maybe we can find something useful in there.

Comment: @xpac added a link to the log from starting the server... It doesn't look very interesting to me. I didn't bother logging into a client to catch that in the log... All it says is "so-n-so logged in at such time"

Comment: Yeah, the log is rather useless. Sorry, I have no better idea at the moment. BTW - while googling I found this, maybe it could be an alternative for you? http://www.a3res.com/home/

Comment: @xpac thanks anyway. I know there are some servers up, but my buddy and I wanted to rip through the game with shall we say extra abilities ... Just for nostalgia's sake

Comment: `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_low_latency`?

Comment: @TechnikEmpire I did this (just now). Is there anything else I might need to do? I see there is ip_forwarding... I have not messed with any network stuff on the linux box, only my router

Comment: @Andy It's supposed to provide hinting that TCP connections will disable the TCP NAGLE algorithm, an algorithm that holds back packets until they have reached a certain size in other to avoid flooding networks with lots of small packets. Given that the source mentions that the server can only serve a relatively small number of clients, I was taking a stab in the dark that its pure TCP and thinking this might be the issue. Total guess, but worth a shot.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire I see, that makes sense. Did not do the trick, though.